# Optional key in JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

Input content (somejson.json) is

```
{ "m1": "1 some m1", "m2": null , "m3" : "unwanted"}
{ "m1": "2 some m1", "m3" : "unwanted"}
{ "m1": "3 some m1", "m2": "3 some m2" , "m3" : "unwanted"}
{ "m1": "4 some m1", "m3" : "unwanted"}
```

Is there an option to extract, say m1. Also extract m2 if exists ?

Example.
For m1 I use the the below command

```
cat somejson.json |jq '.m1'
```

Output

```
"1 some m1"
"2 some m1"
"3 some m1"
"4 some m1"
```

For m2 I use the the below command

```
cat somejson.json |jq '.m2'
```

Output

```
null
null
"3 some m2"
null
```

But I want a merged results including both m1 and m2 like below

```
"1 some m1"
"2 some m1"
"3 some m1"
"3 some m2"
"4 some m1"
```

Comment: Adiseshan - Please resolve the inconsistency regarding the stated requirements and the example.

Comment: @peak I am sorry, I could not understand what the inconsistency is. Read to update the question. Please correct me.

Comment: @AdiseshanK - Consider the difference between {} and {"key": null}.  The first object has no key named "key", but `{} | .key` and `{"key": null}` both yield `null`.  See also Amaden's comment: "That text is inconsistent with the sample data."

Comment: @peek I removed the misleading word "key".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get both values; they will be `null` if they don't exist. Then just filter the nulls from the result.

```
<somejson.json jq '.m1, .m2 | select(. != null)'
```

Comment: @peak: Actually, you are wrong. `jq` is not JavaScript, so `false != null`; so `false` is properly detected. `null` is dropped, but that is actually OP's requirement (per `"m2": null` case in the first object not being reflected in the output). Unless you are arguing that the requirement is to extract `m1` _always_?

Comment: Yes, the requirement if read literally is based on the existence of the key, not on whether it is non-null.

Comment: @peak Again, no. Look at the sample data and desired result. Words can be misleading; code and data are unambiguous.

Comment: Yes, but the requirement says: `Also extract m2 if exists`. Maybe it would be best to ask the OP to resolve the inconsistency.

Comment: @peak Can you stop? That text is inconsistent with the sample data, and I choose to trust the data. This is the third time I repeat the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

To always extract `m1`:

```
jq '.m1, if (.m2 != null) then .m2 else empty end' somejson.json
```

Comment: This does not technically meet the stated requirements if m2 exists and is equal to null.